# first connect to mongodb using webix and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webix

I find webix interesting, so I want to use webix to visualise some informations from my DB.
I have node.js installed, and mongodb that are running well.

What should I do to display data from my DataBase?
Please step by step, cause I'm beginner.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Amine Haddar, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid you're asking in the wrong place; this site is for narrow questions about specific programming problems, not for broad advice on how to start programming a system.

Comment: yes I want to delete it

Answer (score 0):

Webix is a client-side library, it can't connect directly to a database. You need some kind of script on as server side (REST endpoint).

Check more details here

http://docs.webix.com/desktop__server_rest.html